# Rspec tests failing with unexpected message :articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I'm using Devise with Rspec. So I've two model called User and Article which is article belongs_to the user

When run `rspec`, i got an error which is say:

```
1) ArticlesController POST #create with valid attributes saves the article

Failure/Error: post :create, { article: valid_attributes }
   #<Double "user"> received unexpected message :articles with (no args)
   # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:17:in `create'
   # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Below is my `articles_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @article ||= Article.new
  render
end

def create
  @article = @user.articles.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path, notice: "Well done brah! Your article has been publish"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

`spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }
  let (:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article) }

describe "POST #create" do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "saves the article" do
      sign_in
      post :create, { article: valid_attributes }
      expect(Article.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

`spec/factories/articles.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title "Article Title"
    content "Article Content"
    default_image "default_image"
    user
    category
  end
end
```

Where is my mistake? I stuck here

**UPDATED**

`spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller

end
```

`spec/support/controller_helpers.rb`

```
module ControllerHelpers
  def sign_in(user = double('user'))
    if user.nil?
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
    else
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    end
  end
end
```

Both of the updated file above i got it from DEvise wiki - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Comment: The error is not in the code you have provided. Somewhere in your test setup you are injecting a double for the user. I'm guessing its in your `sign_in` method.

Please include the relevant parts of your `spec/rails_helper.rb` and any  session related test helpers that your have.

Comment: @max i've updated my question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an actual database record for your user*.

```
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:valid_session) { sign_in(user) }

  describe "POST #create" do
    before { valid_session }
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves the article" do
        # less prone to false positives
        expect do
          post :create, { article: valid_attributes }
        end.to change(Article, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

We use `expect {}.to change` since you can get a false positive if the database is not cleaned out properly.

`Devise::TestHelpers` already has a `sign_in` function. So get rid of your `ControllerHelpers` module so that your project is not linked to the Devise or Warden internals.

Comment: * Well you could setup the double to fake all the database interaction but that would not be a very good test since you might be covering up bugs.

Comment: Oh well.. it works nicely... thank you for your help advise.. will remove the ````ControllerHellper```` then.. thanks alot